Salesforce create-job-bulk-api-v2 Upsert operation for UpdateOnly
I'm using salesforce create-job-bulk-api-v2 with Upsert operation in Mule 4 and as per this documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.250.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_upsert_patch.htm we can prevent new records to be created and use this to update only. How can I set updateOnly to True, I tried using this
<salesforce:create-job-bulk-api-v2 objectType="Account" operation="upsert" doc:name="Create job bulk api v 2" doc:id="c43d3dc1-0f9f-416e-9c2d-9330a9861cb4" config-ref="Salesforce_Config" externalIdFieldName="External_Id_c">
                <salesforce:headers >
                    <salesforce:header key="updateOnly" value="true" />
                </salesforce:headers>
    </salesforce:create-job-bulk-api-v2>

but still new contact is being created.
Can someone please help me with that?
Thanks
